# Mock amazon web service Request/Response object in junit

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, junit, mockito

I am working in AWS(Amazon web service) , mockito and java junit4 environment. In my class I am using one method which takes Request object as a parameter and depending on that object I am getting response. Following is my code,

```
private Response<String> getStringResponse(Request<?> request) {
        try {
            AmazonHttpClient client = new AmazonHttpClient(new ClientConfiguration());
            ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext(true);
            HttpResponseHandler<AmazonClientException> handler = getErrorResponseHandler();
            HttpResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = getHttpResponseHandler();
            RequestExecutionBuilder requestExecutionBuilder = client.requestExecutionBuilder();
            requestExecutionBuilder = requestExecutionBuilder.executionContext(executionContext);
            requestExecutionBuilder = requestExecutionBuilder.request(request);
            requestExecutionBuilder = requestExecutionBuilder.errorResponseHandler(handler);
            Response<String> response = requestExecutionBuilder.execute(responseHandler);
            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLogger.getLogger().error("Exception in :: classname :: getStringResponse() ::");
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is, I want to mock this whole scenario means on whatever request, my method should give me the custom response object which I want, irrespective of what Request is coming. I am calling this method from my junit test. So is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Read [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html) to get the bacis idea. Then you'll be able to answer your question yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can test this method with JUnit and Mockito, 
you should write a clean and **testable codes**.
Importantly, you have to **remove all dependencies inside method** and initialize them from outside. For example,

```
 private Response<String> getStringResponse(Request<?> request,
      AmazonHttpClient client,
      ExecutionContext executionContext,
      HttpResponseHandler<AmazonClientException> handler,
      HttpResponseHandler<String> responseHandler) {
    try {
      RequestExecutionBuilder requestExecutionBuilder = client.requestExecutionBuilder()
          .executionContext(executionContext)
          .request(request)
          .errorResponseHandler(handler);
      Response<String> response = requestExecutionBuilder.execute(responseHandler);
      return response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      AppLogger.getLogger().error("Exception in :: classname :: getStringResponse() ::");
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Now you can test it by mocking these above dependencies.

```
  @Mock
  AmazonHttpClient client;
  @Mock
  ExecutionContext executionContext;
  @Mock
  HttpResponseHandler<AmazonClientException> handler;
  @Mock    
  HttpResponseHandler<String> responseHandler;

  // For request, you can create a custom one or use mock data
  Request<?> request;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    // other setups
  }

  @Test
  public void getStringResponseTest() {
    // you can test now
    yourCall.getStringResponse(request, client, executionContext, handler, responseHandler);
    // verify whatever you want....
  }
```

Comment: Actually I am unable to modify my method, is there any other way